# Application in android, that create hotspot are disclosed by this application only

Tags: android, hotspot

I am trying to write application that created hotspot on one device, and on other device, the application shows a list of all these networks (i.e list of all networks in the range created by this app).

I want that these networks can not be detected by another devices/applications.

It is possible? How?

Thanks!

Comment: You're asking how to hide a SSID from a broadcasting hotspot?

Comment: @cricket_007 Not exactly. I asked how to hide the network from everyone, except the application that created it.

Comment: That doesn't seem possible. You might be able to set the SSID to a specific name, but that will only hide from a list of "available networks", there are still tools that exist to scan that frequency and see the network broadcasting. I think a simple password-protected network should be fine

Comment: @cricket_007 This need is not for security, but for style..

Comment: Are you trying to make something like a [mesh network](http://www.opengarden.com/meshkit.html)?